# codeIgniter can't access session in Hook

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, hook

I have created on hook to set current visiting URL to session. I have to use this URL later on. I have called session method of codeIgniter using `$this->CI =& get_instance();` and then `$this->CI->session->userdata` but it is giving

> Trying to get property of non-object on `$this->CI->session->userdata` line

I have done following things to enable **hooks** in CI

**config.php**

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

**hooks.php**

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
        'class'    => 'Preclass',
        'function' => 'checkreq',
        'filename' => 'preclass.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks',
        'params'   => array()
);
```

**preclass.php**

```
class Preclass
{
    private $CI;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();

    }
    public function checkreq($value='')
    {
        var_dump($this->CI->session->userdata);
        die;
    }
}
```

Note: Don't close this post as Duplicate of PHP errors. As I know about errors. This is in CodeIgniter and I want to check session before any controller method gets invoked.

Comment: why do you need this information in your session ?

Comment: I want to modify some data in session @sintakonte

Comment: @sintakonte here I will explain my problem: I want to redirect user according to their type(which is set in session). So if user tries to go to other action from typing in url (which does not allow to him) then it redirect it to specific controller. I know I can use `post_controller_constructor` but I want this before any of `constructor` invoked as I dont want un-necessary execution of code

Comment: the thing is - i think you misunderstand the concept here - a pre system hook or something like that is good if you've something abstract which is system immanent (e.g. an autoloader) but not application relevant - in this case however you've a clear task - go for a parent controller e.g. `MY_Controller` and try to implement the logic there - CI is built for that, and the overhead shouldn't concern you @all... because the loading time should be below 100ms anyways...

Comment: agreed, a simple my controller condition should handle this quite nicely. i use it show an error page if the user isn't authenticated for a certain controller/method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comment: "But I want it before controller methods invoke even before constructor"

To solve your issue, this is about the best you can do:

Make an `MY_Controller.php` in `application/core`:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // class is just an alias for the controller name
        if (!$this->user->is_allowed($this->router->class)) {
            redirect('somepage');
        }
    }

}
```

Then have all your controllers extend `MY_Controller`:

```
class Somecontroller extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // nothing below the above line will be reached
        // if the user isn't allowed
    }

}
```

Whether or not you have a `__construct()` method in the class: nothing will happen so long as the user isn't allowed to access the page e.g. nothing after `parent::__construct()` will be called - even methods. Again, the fact that the parent constructor is called is implied if no constructor exists for the controller.

*Note: if you autoload a model and do the same logic in the `MY_Controller` in the models `__construct()` the same results should be achieved. I just find this method cleaner.*

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Codeigniter as `session` itself a library and you are trying to call it `pre_controller`. When controllers not loaded yet how can you use it even in hook.

## Solution

You may use `post_controller_constructor` instead what are using now

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
        'class'    => 'Preclass',
        'function' => 'checkreq',
        'filename' => 'preclass.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks',
        'params'   => array()
);
```

otherwise you may also use native session here

hope it help

Comment: But I want it before controller methods invoke even before `constructor`. So is there any way rather than `$_SESSION`?

Comment: @B.Desai as far as codeigniter concern and i know NO

Comment: But it will lead me to issue later on when controller will invoked *ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time* as I have to write `session_start();` in class to use `$_SESSION`

Comment: If you are using the CI `session` library you do not - actually should not - make a call to `session_start()`. The `session` library takes care of that for you making `$_SESSION` immediately available.